# Python 2.7 and Pandas merge 2 csv files with Forex Data

Tags: python, csv, merge, pandas, forex

I have two csv files

1: eurusd.csv
2: xauusd.csv

there is no header in the files, but the data is Date Time, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume. each file has the following type of data...

eurusd.csv:

```
02/23/2009 18:01,1.27090,1.27110,1.27040,1.27050,204
02/23/2009 18:02,1.27060,1.27060,1.27000,1.27040,211
02/23/2009 18:03,1.27040,1.27050,1.27010,1.27040,82
02/23/2009 18:04,1.27020,1.27080,1.27020,1.27060,98
```

xauusd.csv

```
02/23/2009 18:01,991.260,992.120,990.800,991.840,69
02/23/2009 18:02,991.800,992.260,991.200,991.870,74
02/23/2009 18:04,991.820,991.830,990.700,991.320,74
```

I want to merge the data based on the date time column which is the first column in both files. as you can see the second file does not have exact same records as the first file, so missing some data from second file, but thats ok. I want to bring the Close column from second file to the first file based on matching date tile field between them

so the final merged csv file will have the following columns... 
Date Time, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, CloseFromSecondCsv

merged.csv

```
02/23/2009 18:01,1.27090,1.27110,1.27040,1.27050,204,991.840
02/23/2009 18:02,1.27060,1.27060,1.27000,1.27040,211,991.870
02/23/2009 18:03,1.27040,1.27050,1.27010,1.27040,82,0
02/23/2009 18:04,1.27020,1.27080,1.27020,1.27060,98,991.320
```

im not sure how to do this. thanks in advance

---

Final working code based on TomAugspurger's answer:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("C:\IQFEED\XAUUSDO.COMP_1.csv", index_col=0, names=['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'], parse_dates=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv("C:\IQFEED\EURUSD.COMP_1.csv", index_col=0, names=['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'], parse_dates=True)
df2['other_close'] = df1['close']
df2.fillna(0)
df2.to_csv('C:\IQFEED\python.csv')
```

---

I figured out using column numbers only way...

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("C:\IQFEED\XAUUSD.txt", index_col=0, usecols=[0,4], parse_dates=True, header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv("C:\IQFEED\EURUSD.txt", index_col=0, usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5], parse_dates=True, header=None)
df2[6] = df1[4]
df2.to_csv('C:\IQFEED\python1.csv')
```

Comment: are they meant to be on a different day (is that a typo)? I don't understand how this would make any sense (why just copy the Close value?)

Comment: Andy, sorry that was mistake on my part. that was a typo, i fixed it and edited the original post. why just copy the close value is I am using Altreva Adaptive Modeler and it allows to model based on a single instrument and the latest version allows you to add another data point in the modeling as well, so I am choosing gold close price to use in the modeler. I can only use single additional column, otherwise ill use all columns from second csv file, but for now just close or column #4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, Andy had the right idea in his comment.  You don't want to merge to two, you want to copy the column of one into the other.

```
In [48]: df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(b), index_col=0, names=['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'], parse_dates=True)


In [49]: df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(a), index_col=0, names=['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'], parse_dates=True)


In [71]: df1
Out[71]: 
                       open    high    low   close  volume
time                                                      
2009-02-23 18:01:00  991.26  992.12  990.8  991.84      69
2009-02-23 18:02:00  991.80  992.26  991.2  991.87      74
2009-02-23 18:04:00  991.82  991.83  990.7  991.32      74

In [72]: df2
Out[72]: 
                       open    high     low   close  volume
time                                                       
2009-02-23 18:01:00  1.2709  1.2711  1.2704  1.2705     204
2009-02-23 18:02:00  1.2706  1.2706  1.2700  1.2704     211
2009-02-23 18:03:00  1.2704  1.2705  1.2701  1.2704      82
2009-02-23 18:04:00  1.2702  1.2708  1.2702  1.2706      98





In [51]: df2['other_close'] = df1['close']


In [52]: df2
Out[52]: 
                       open    high     low   close  volume  other_close
time                                                                    
2009-02-23 18:01:00  1.2709  1.2711  1.2704  1.2705     204       991.84
2009-02-23 18:02:00  1.2706  1.2706  1.2700  1.2704     211       991.87
2009-02-23 18:03:00  1.2704  1.2705  1.2701  1.2704      82          NaN
2009-02-23 18:04:00  1.2702  1.2708  1.2702  1.2706      98       991.32
```

You can do `df2.fillna(0)` to get your expected answer.

Comment: here is what I tried:
    import pandas as pd
    df1 = pd.read_csv("C:\IQFEED\XAUUSDO.COMP_1.csv", index_col=0,names=['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'], parse_dates=True)
    df2 = pd.read_csv("C:\IQFEED\EURUSD.COMP_1.csv", index_col=0, names=['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'], parse_dates=True)
    df2['other_close'] = df1['close']
    df2.to_csv('C:\IQFEED\python.csv',index=False)

Comment: Thank you Tom, that worked. I edited the final working code above. if you can think of anything else to add or remove from code please let me know. thanks again

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't writing the index column to csv?  Seems like it would be useful to keep.

Comment: not sure how to? will this do it?
df.to_csv("C:\IQFEED\python.csv", index=True)

Comment: Or you can just leave index blank.  It's true by default :). so `df.to_csv("C:\IQFEED\python.csv')`

Comment: Tom, anyway to not use column names but column numbers? like instead of close use column#4 ?

Comment: A few ways.  Either avoid them from the beginning by not passing `names=[ ]` to `read_csv` or replace them before writing with `df.columns = range(len(df.columns))`.  See the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) for reading/writing options.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date and time columns are the same you can just do

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1',sep=r'\s+')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2',sep=r'\s+')

df = pd.merge(df1,df2)
```

And it should merge them using the same columns.

*assuming I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Matt, will the above merge both csv files based on common matching date time in the row? and also will it just add the close or column #4 from the second csv file to the merged file?

Comment: If I remember correctly it will just merge the common columns and add keep all the unique columns as they are.